# Как можно стянуть последний коммит с удаленного репозитория

Tags: git, github, gitlab

У меня есть главная ветка master. Я работаю на второй ветке dev и в тоже время кто-то из команды делает push on master. Как мне получить последние изменения с master сразу на мою ветку dev ?

Comment: В современных IDE просто пулите репозиторий, потом мержите master в dev.

Answer (score 0):

Как-то так:

```sh
git fetch
git rebase master
```

Comment: так вроде origin называлось? или уже и сюда добрались и переименовали в upstream? но тогда почему не main?

Comment: ммм, да - пожалуй в данном вопросе оно будет скорее всего 'origin'. Я обычно с github flow работаю, там принято "главный" репозиторий называть upstream.

Comment: @Nikita  `git pull --rebase origin master`.